# Jmockit String final length method mocking Issue

Tags: java, mocking, testng, jmockit

Using jmockit 1.2 jar,
Trying to mock String's length method but getting Unexpected Invocation Exception:

```
FAILED: test
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point;      please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock   field or parameter
at StringDemo.TestA$1.<init>(TestA.java:17)
at StringDemo.TestA.test(TestA.java:13)
```

I am using testNG:

```
@Test
   public void test() throws Exception
   {
    new Expectations()
      {
        @Mocked("length")
        String aString;
         {
            aString.length();
            result = 2;
         }
      };

      System.out.println(A.showA("test"));
   }
}
```

Actual class A:

```
public class A {
public static int showA(String str){
    int a= str.length();
    return a;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way of recording the expected results. You shouldn't mock and record String's `length()` method, record your `showA()` instead. here is the solution

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {

        new Expectations()
        {
            @NonStrict
            final Source mock = null;

            {
                Source.showA(anyString);
                result = 2;
            }
        };

        assertEquals(2, Source.showA("test"));
    }
```

Comment: Yup I was doing that only previously. But as I was able to mock getBytes method of String so I thought it should work for length as well. Can you tell me the exact reason why it doesn't work for length method ?

Comment: The `String#length()` method is one of a few that are not mockable by JMockit 1.x. The reason for this set of non-mockable JRE methods to exist is that they are known to cause issues in JMockit 1.x if mocked.

Comment: @Rogério - that's good to know.  It this documented anywhere?

Comment: It's not documented, for lack of a good place to insert such details, and mostly because it shouldn't come up in the first place. Mocking a method like `String#length()` is not something you should normally do.